# Is this a valid proof? Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

**Fifteen squirrels gather $100$ nuts. Prove that two of the squirrels gathered the same number of nuts.**

I am fully aware that this is a very elementary problem but I just need to make sure my method of proof is acceptable.

So this is what my proof was:

If each squirrel gathered a unique number of nuts, then:

$1 + 2 +\cdots+15 = 120$

$120$ is greater than $105$, therefore, at least two squirrels gathered the same number of nuts.

However, the proof in the solutions manual was as follows:

For each $i = 1, 2, \ldots , 15,$ let $x_i$ be the number of nuts gathered by squirrel $i$. Sort the $x_i$’s so that $x_1 ≤ x_2 ≤ · · · ≤ x_{15}$. If all the inequalities are strict, then $x_i ≥ i − 1$ for all $i$, and therefore $\sum x_i ≥ 105$.

The above proof seems to be quite technical though it does make sense. But I just wanted to know if my proof is sufficient or is the level or technicality in the official solutions the only acceptable method?

Comment: Firstly, it's possible that one of the squirrels gather zero nuts.

Comment: Secondly, assuming no two squirrels gathered the same number of nuts, you can't automatically assume the counts are consecutive. The book solution deals with this issue by proving lower bounds. So while your attempt captures the essence of why the claim holds, it's too informal to qualify as a correct answer.

Comment: I wonder why you have compared 120 with 105 rather than with 100.

Comment: @quasi should not the statement "if all the inequalities are strict, then $x_i≥i−1$ for all $i$" be firstly proved?

Comment: Your solution assumes that each squirrel gathered at least 1 nut  but the manual only assumes that each squirrel gathered a non-negative integer number of nuts.

Comment: If you include zero nuts, then you get $0 + 1 + ... +14 = 105 > 100$.